# Win Forms chart not updating with BindingList (Intermittent) when reading from serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, charts, serial-port

Strangely, when I `Add(i)` to my `BindingList<int> list`, the value is not added to my chart. But if I `Add(34)` in a different place, the chart updates. On some runs, it actually updates once, adding one value to the chart. So far I have tried two versions, one using the `SerialDataReceived`, and the other, using a `BackgroundWorker`.

Data Recieved:

```c#
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<int> list = new BindingList<int>();
    string[] ports = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();// chart1 has default values; unchanged

        ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboPorts.DataSource = ports;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.DataSource = list;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "list";

        list.Add(34);//Displays on chart fine
        list.Add(12);//same here

    }

    private void comboPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboPorts.SelectedValue.ToString();
            serialPort1.Open();
            labelPortStatus.Text = "Port Open";
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            labelPortStatus.Text = "Problem: " + exc.Message;
        }

    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0; ;
        string s = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        if (s.StartsWith("t"))
        {
            i = Convert.ToInt32(s.TrimStart('t'));

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                labelTemperature.Text = i.ToString();//label updates with values correctly
            });


        }
        else if (s.StartsWith("h"))
        {
            i = Convert.ToInt32(s.TrimStart('h'));

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                labelHumidity.Text = i.ToString();//label updates with values correctly
            });
        }

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            list.Add(i);// 10% of the time, one or two values may be added to the chart.
            // list.Add(56); //  same for adding an int directly
        });
    }
}
```

BackgrroundWorker:

```c#
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboPorts.DataSource = ports;

        chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.DataSource = list;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "list";
        list.Add(34); // check if chart binding works (works fine)
        list.Add(12);
    }

    private void comboPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            workerSerial.CancelAsync();
        }

        try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboPorts.SelectedValue.ToString();
            serialPort1.Open();
            labelPortStatus.Text = "Port Open";
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            labelPortStatus.Text = "Problem: " + exc.Message;
        }
        workerSerial.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void workerSerial_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (serialPort1.IsOpen || !workerSerial.CancellationPending)
        {
            int i = 0; ;
            string s = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            if (s.StartsWith("t"))
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(s.TrimStart('t'));

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                labelTDisp.Text = i.ToString();//works as it should
                });
                workerSerial.ReportProgress(1);

            }
            else if (s.StartsWith("h"))
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(s.TrimStart('h'));

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                labelHDisp.Text = i.ToString();// works as it should
                });
                workerSerial.ReportProgress(1);


            }

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                list.Add(i);// 10% of the time, one or two values may be added to the chart.
             // list.Add(56); //  same for adding an int directly
            });
            workerSerial.ReportProgress(1);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        workerSerial.ReportProgress(2);
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;

    }

    private void workerSerial_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        labelListItems.Text = list.Count.ToString();// display list.count; correct no. of items
        switch (e.ProgressPercentage)
        {
            case 1:
                labelPortStatus.Text = "Serial Active...";
                return;
            case 2:
                labelPortStatus.Text = "Serial Stopped;";
                return;
            case 3:
                labelPortStatus.Text = "Problem...";
                return;
        }

    }

    private void workerSerial_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBoxRunSerial_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelListItems.Text = list.Count.ToString();
        if (checkBoxRunSerial.Checked && !workerSerial.IsBusy)
        {
            workerSerial.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            workerSerial.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The Serial port transmits every second. There may be other problems in the code, but its only rough to get the chart working.

Comment: It must be inside `Invoke`, since `DataReceived` event is raised on non UI thread, hence the `ListChanged` (raised by the `BindingList` when you call `Add`) will also be raised on non UI thread if you don't use `Invoke` or similar, which will break the UI listening to that event.

Comment: I thought so, but it doesn't even work when inside `Invoke` (as I stated in code).

Comment: I've noticed that. Still it's a must :)

Comment: Ok, I'll update the code in a bit. It's a start anyway. ;]

Comment: Actually looking at the source code, looks like `Chart` is not listening to the `ListChanged` event at all. The first data binding occurs on first `Paint`, so the `// check if chart binding works` has no effect (the binding update does not work at all)

Comment: If it's unclear, I meant the source code of the `Chart` class, not yours :) Shortly, you cannot rely on `BindingList` notifications for updating the chart. I would suggest after adding a value to the list, do `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(chart1.DataBind));`

Comment: Ok, that seems to work, lol. Should I be using this `BindingList` method or something else, what would you suggest? Will I have this problem with other binding methods too?

Comment: It's a defect in `Chart` data binding implementation - one way, one time (the chart is updated only from `DataBind` method). So in this case it doesn't matter if you use `List`, `BindingList`, `BindingSource` etc. - any time you change the underlying source (add/remove/update), you need to call `DataBind` in order to reflect the changes :(

Comment: Maybe the first two `Add`s ( by `//check if chart binding works`) were added to the chart because they were in the `Form1` constructor? Coz it's strange that not only did the first two `list.Add`s get added to the chart (before the form is shown), but the problem `list.Add(i)` also got added, but intermittently and only one or two chart values per run. I'm sure I read on MSDN that `BindingList` sends an update message to the chart, unlike `List` which doesn't. That's why I used `BindingList` in the first place. Are you sure this issue isn't caused by thread-related problems or something else?

Comment: After looking at the source code, yes, I'm sure. So disregard my first two comments, they apply for controls that correctly support data binding notifications. And you are right for the first two `Add` calls. If you simply insert `chart1.DataBind();` *before* them, the chart will be empty :) The problem is not the `BindingList` (it raises `ListChanged` notifications), the proplem is that `Chart` does not subscribe to that event, hence cannot receive the notifications sent and react appropriately.

Comment: Ah, right. Well, thanks for your time anyway, it's working fine now. If you want to add a summary as an answer, I'll accept it; It's up to you.

Comment: You are welcome mate, glad it helped :) I think I'll stay with comments (thanks for proposing, to be honest, just feel lazy to compose an answer :), take care.